# What is the best way for creating a web report

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports, ssrs-2012

I have an asp.net based website and I need to create a designed report, so the customer can watch and print.
The report is a collect list, which contains a table and additional data.
What is the best way to create it? Crystal reports? SSRS? Maybe some other tech?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

SSRS is dead easy and really simple to knock up if you have a reasonable SQL understanding.

I work on a very complex account for contract reporting. We have over 132 contract conditions which the customer is able to view our performance at any given point in time for any period of time.

We also have over 100 reports for Operations etc. We do rarely touch them once created in SSRS and deploy them.

I have recently even began goofing around with making reports that the user can customize themselves (eg: Hiding Adding Columns)

SSRS is by far the best scaled solution.